# react-app-rewired used to enable web workers fails to build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, web-worker

I'm using `react-app-rewired` because I'm using web workers in my project. So when I attempt to build everything goes fine but inside the build folder there is no `index.html` or any js file. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my `config-overrides` file:

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.worker\.js$/,
        use: { loader: 'worker-loader' }
    });
    config.output.globalObject = 'this';
    return config;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding **// eslint-disable-line no-restricted-globals** to the worker file (myworker.worker.js).

**Example:**

```
self.addEventListener("message", getMessage); // eslint-disable-line no-restricted-globals

function getMessage(event) {
  let message = event.data;
  postMessage(message); //just relay back to main thread
}
```